# Programmatically change font size of text selection using CKEditor

Tags: ckeditor, rich-text-editor

I'm trying to use CKEditor simply as an API that I can drive with my own UI.

Firstly, is this the right use of CKEditor?

If so, how could I modify the font size of a text selection programmatically?

Comment: I have used it more than 10 projects. seems to be ok.

Comment: Can you elaborate then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Creating own UI for CKEditor

It's a doable approach, but for some cases it might be tough and require some code duplication.

There are older parts of CKE that encapsulate many useful things, so you have no convenient API to access it from outside.

### Adding a font size

The minimal effort would be to simply use [CKEDITOR.style](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.style) objects.

```
var editor = CKEDITOR.instances.editor1;
var style = new CKEDITOR.style( {
    element: 'span',
    styles: { 'font-size': '20px' }
} );

editor.applyStyle( style );
```

For more examples see [font plugin](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/blob/master/plugins/font/plugin.js#L60), you're interested in fontSize combobox.

Comment: And if I were to apply a similar style, this time with font size 30px, would it handle that well and reuse the span?

Comment: Well, you could try this yourself simply in a console. Yes it will reuse existing span if possible.

Comment: It doesn't seem to reuse an available span.

<span style="font-size:48px;"><span class="titleText">Text</span></span>

I need the font-size style to be merged into the .titleText span.

Comment: @mdupls: That's a whole new question and to answer it we would need more details. It's absolutely not obvious when do you want to merge them and the answer may be from trivial to absolutely impossible :D.

Comment: @Reinmar Thanks. I've posted a new question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28030449/use-my-existing-rich-text-ui-with-ckeditor-apis